# Simplest way to filter a list of objects by boolean value and select object key?

Tags: javascript

I want to filter the object of booleans and then select the key name of the true item in the most efficient way, drawing a blank on selecting the active key name.

```
const winners = {
lg: false
md: true
sm: false
xs: false
}

const active = Object.entries(winners).filter(([key, bool]) => !!bool)[0][0]
//this seems quite ugly, can I chain active or flatten the list to get the key 'md'?
```

**Maybe something like this:**

```
const [key, value] = Object.entries(winners).filter(([key, bool]) => !!bool)[0]
```

Comment: Was messing around with the outcome with some trial and error @trincot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a **readable** solution which gets **all** true keys, then

```js
true_keys = Object.keys(winners).filter(key=>winners[key]);
```

isn't a bad choice.

If you want speed them [@domenikk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63493720/9063935) is the way to go, but otherwise readability is usually preferable over maximum efficiency (I mean, you *are* using JS).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a for loop:

```
let winnerKey = null;

for(let key in winners) {
    if(winners[key]) {
       winnerKey = key;
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: While not as readable, this is definitely your fastest bet

Answer (score 1):

Can use `pickBy`, with some sort of destructuring:

```
function pickBy(object) {
    const obj = {};
    for (const key in object) {
        if (object[key]) {
            obj[key] = object[key];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
const [key, value] = Object.entries(pickBy(winners))[0]
```

- https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Lodash-Underscore#_pickby

You could also use a reduce:

```
Object.entries(winners).reduce((p, [key, value]) => value ? key : p, null)

"md"

Object.entries({}).reduce((p, [key, value]) => value ? key : p, null)

null
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this:

```
const winners = {
lg: false,
md: true,
sm: false,
xs: false,
}
const active = Object.keys(winners).filter(key => winners[key])[0]
```

Do not you think that array of object is more suitable store for winners? Like

```
const winners = [
  {
    name: "lg",
    is_winner: false
  },
  {
    name: "md",
    is_winner: true
  },
  ...
]
```

That way you could easily manage the list of winners - add, delete, filter etc. To create that kind of storage you can use

```
const winnersArray = Object.keys(winners).map(key => ({ "name": key, "is_winner": winners[key] }))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop iterating as soon as a `true` is found.

```js
const test = {
  lg: false,
  md: true,
  sm: false,
  xs: false
}

const winner = Object.keys(test)[Object.values(test).indexOf(true)]

console.log(winner)
```